# ColdFusion CFC returning record count

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Question: I have a CFM calling my CFC on the cfform action line:

In my CFC, I have output="false".  I am needing the record count sent back to my CFM. When I run my CFM and enter the form info my queries are running successfully, but it is not coming back to my CFM so I can display the proper messages.  I just get the CFC page with my record count.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code??

Comment: As it is now, here is my <cfform line.

Comment: <cfform line: <cfform action="customers.cfc?method=ModifyCustomers" method="post">.  Is correct?  Sorry, I am new at this!

Comment: I'd suggest something along the lines of what @Billy Cravens suggested below.  Is there any particular reason you have to be submitting the form to a CFC versus submitting it a regular .cfm page that simply calls a CFC?

Answer (score 3):

Since there's no code, making a few assumptions here about how you're doing things ....

Don't point to the CFC, point to a CFM page in your `<cfform>`. (If you omit the action, it'll point back to itself.. I like self-referencing form pages)

In your CFC, return the result struct from your query:

```
<cfquery datasource="#ds#" name="myQuery" result="myResult">
    INSERT INTO myTable .....
</cfquery>
```

Then either return that entire struct, or just `myResult.recordCount`:

```
<cfreturn myResult.recordCount>
```

Then in your CFM page, you'll access it like so (assuming you're using `<cfscript>`; similar if you're doing tag-based):

```
recordsAdded = createObject('component','myFolder.myCFC').insertMethod(form);
```

Comment: The createObject method itself won't return an instance of the component so the insertMethod function woulnd't be available.  You'd need to do createObject('component','myFolder.myCFC').init().insertMethod(form); where the init method returned "this"

Comment: To add a tip, if you are using SQL Server 2k5+ you can use the OUTPUT clause to actually return all of the inserted data including the key.  Then you can return the query results to be used if need be, along with myQuery.recordCount.

Comment: @bittersweetryan Actually, init() isn't necessary, unless you have additional constructor code that needs to run (and in CF9, constructors are implicit, no need to execute explicitly)

Comment: Billy - I was assuming it was < CF9.  I don't assume I'm looking at CF9 code unless I see the new keyword in place of createObject or script based cfc's.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the cfform line to this:

      
....rest of my form

then added these lines to see if the form was submitted and what action is:

```
<!--- create object for cfc --->
```

But now, my query is not running....